# Iterating shapefiles using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

What tool can I use to run many shapefiles to intersect with a shapefile as a output?

It looks like that Iterate tools is use for feature classes or datasets and I don't see any for the shapefile.

I can use the Batch but I want to use ModelBuilder because I might need to add more tools later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A shapefile is a kind of feature class, like an FGDB feature class or an SDE feature class. Use [iterate feature classes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Classes/00400000000r000000/) in modelbuilder. You can then output as a feature class, and if it is named correctly (`c:\path\to\directory\that\exists\output.shp`) you will get a shapefile out.