# Iterate incidents for closest facility analysis (Network Analyst) using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, iterator, closest-facility

I have created a model for closest facility analysis. Now I would like to add an iterator to it. Specifically, I need to iterate through 448 "Incidents" (the closest facility model is structured so that it solves from incidents to facilities). Each of the incidents is stored as a shapefile in a folder (one feature per shapefile). So, I would use the "Files" iterator, presumably. But not sure how. Below is a screenshot of the model as currently constructed.

[image: Current model]

Comment: Before answering your question, why do you have one feature per shapefile? Would it be possible to merge all your incidents features into one shapefile? If so, you would be able to calculate the closest facility for each feature in one go. Afterwards you could split the faetures again in different files if desired.

Comment: As I understand closest facility, if I ran it in one go, it would find the nearest incident relative to each facility. That's not what I want. I want a discrete closest facility analysis for every building at the site. That is, from every building to a given destination. Then iterate to the next destination, etc until every building has its own closest facility map. Later, I will combine them all for a from everywhere-to everywhere aggregate traffic map of the site (archaeological simulation of foot traffic).

Comment: Can you do a "for loop" from the model builder that iterates over every records in your feature class?

Comment: I can't get that to work. Never worked with the For iterator. Don't think that it is the correct iterator. I need a single point to be the incident in the model. One at a time. I believe Closest Facility does not limit analysis only to selected point(s). Rather, it will run them on all loaded locations.

Comment: I'm not sure I have my head around your problem... but since you mention "everywhere-to-everywhere," I wonder if you might be able to use an OD Cost Matrix. (You would still need to merge your shapefiles into one, as Jelle suggested.) See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00470000004r000000

Comment: You're misunderstanding how CF works. It looks for the closest facility to any given incident. You want to be iterating facilities, *not* incidents. If you do incidents, you get one route from that incident to its nearest facility, not all the routes from every incident to a given facility. And there's no reason to have separate files - you can iterate on facility id and use a select tool to isolate that one point as your facility input to the solver (yes it runs on all loaded but it respects selections in loading). @Andy ODCM doesn't create routes, or it would be best and no model needed.

Comment: In fact, if you have building points and you want from every building to every other building, you don't even need two files. The entire point file will be loaded in as incidents, and you'll stick a [feature selection iterator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00400000000s000000) in front of your facility input. The points feed into the iterator, it selects one point and shoves it out as selected features, which you then feed into the CF tool as the sole facility input. Might need a make feature layer in between the iterator and CF tool.

Comment: Chris re: facilities/incidents: the model can be set up to run from facilities to incidents or from incidents to facilities. I am setting it up from facilities to incidents because the dialog window for Make Closest Facility Layer only has an option for # of Facilities to Find (not one for Number of Incidents to Find). Thus, I enter the total N of Facilities (in this case, 449), and then select a single incident. So the model runs from every facility to a single incident. Re: feature selection iterator: I'll try that, using the same input file for facilities and incidents.

Comment: Chris: Thank you! Actually, you are right. It will run either way, but I was working against the grain of the tool. I set it up as # of facilities to find = 1, then use the feature selection iterator on Add Locations (Facilities) (and setting it as a precondition). I'll post an image of the model soon and mark this as solved.

Comment: Still not working. I think I'm missing something obvious. The image in the original post shows the model as currently constructed (I updated it). The log shows that the model runs correctly one time, selecting ObjectID = 1, and on subsequent runs, the iterator fails--it selects all 448 records as facilities. A second, perhaps related issue (this is also probably obvious): I need to output the route shapefiles with names using the ObjectID from the corresponding iteration. The Copy Features tool requires a specific name. How to set up the model to use the name of the ObjectID from the iterator?

Comment: The to/from relationship only affects the routes themselves, not the number of them (see travel direction parameter in the [help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004800000028000000)). Huge thanks for the # facilities to find parameter. I haven't used the solver in a while and had totally forgotten about that and now I have some answers to edit. I do think the iterative model approach still has merit for larger datasets or producing individual facility routing files. Looks like you got the file naming taken care of in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Totally crazy how easy the answer is. One doesn't even need to use model builder to iterate through all possible routes. In my case, I have a feature class (points) that represents every doorway at the archaeological site (N=448 doorways). I simply pointed Network Analyst to that feature class for *both* Facilities *and* Incidents, while indicating in the Network Analyst Layer Properties (Analysis Settings tab) to find 448 facilities. That way, for each incident, it will find all 448 facilities. Thus, 448 x 448 = 200,704 routes. Done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using "Iterate Datasets" instead of "Iterate Files". 
I can't tell if "Iterate Datasets" requires GDB feature classes or if it will work on your current shapefiles.

From esri help: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000001n000000.htm

"Iterate Files" specifically skips datasets that are recognized in ArcCatalog (such as shapefiles). http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Files/00400000000v000000/

A previous question found a similar solution: [Iterating shapefiles using ModelBuilder or Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107162/iterating-shapefiles-using-modelbuilder-or-python)